# Magento taxes are not working

Tags: magento-1.9

My Magento shop has the Dutch Tax settings, but I cannot get them to work. I have enabled all the right settings but it will not make any tax changes.

When I add a product to the cart it displays:

[image: No TAX.]

In the backend I give the product a 21% tax rate  with it, and the tax settings are as followed:

[image: Information of shipping]

Has anybody any clue what i am doing wrong? I have been searching through scripts but didn't edit anything. Please help, cant launch now.

*TAX RATES*

[image: tax rates]
[image: Tax rates 2]
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your tax rates that you setup? Also, did you enable the product as a taxable product? If so, which option did you choose?

Comment: @kab8609 see the 2 below images. Is that what you mean? And where do i enable that? In the product creation itself? I give it a price and then a tax class 21% with it.

Comment: When you go into a product to manage it, you should see it in the price section: https://www.dropbox.com/s/17xyn38iqmt01dv/Screenshot%202014-12-15%2012.57.19.png?dl=0

Comment: @kab8609 yes i use there the 21% Omzetbelasting (dutch for tax) for the product. That is what is set-up out of my settings i imported for dutch tax.

Comment: You didn't answer my question at all. Is the tax class "None", "Taxable Goods", or "Shipping" on the product? Also, did you go through the checkout process? Since this is a region, it might not know you are in the Netherlands until you go through the checkout process.

Comment: @kab8609 the tax class is 21% omzetbelasting. That is the class for the 21% goods (standard). When i check the region, it does not change. This answers?

Comment: No, it doesnt. Go to a product of yours in the backend (Catalog -> Manage Product). Go to the price tab, take a screenshot of it and post it.

Comment: @kab8609 See screenshot in post.

Comment: I find it odd that in your price it says [Inc Tax]. I feel like another component is ignoring your tax rate.

Comment: @kab8609 could be a plugin? Extension? Anything?

Comment: A plugin is a synonym for extension. In your version control, can you diff your code to make sure no core code has been rewritten? I would then check to see if any extensions rewrite any tax for price functions. I would go to the un edited magento base theme and see if that is working with tax. If it is still failing after that, I would recommend changing the currency and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been solved. I did not use Taxable goods as title of the attribuut. It changed when i made a tax class with names taxable goods and rate 21%!

How do you set a question to answered on here?

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to ensure the tax class for each product is set correctly.

In your individual products ensure that under General tab that Tax Class is set to Taxable Goods.

You can also do this in bulk by multiselecting all products that don't have Tax Class set correctly and then on the actions drop down select 'Update Attributes' and set as above.

Answer (score 1):

I see your tax calculation is based on shipping origin. If I were to guess: your origin (it's a little below these settings in System Configuration Tax) is still on US. Change that to Netherlands (put * in the rest of the fields) and you should be golden.

Comment: This was already posted like that... Netherlands, and shipping origin were already like that.